# Pre-order decision binary-tree printout

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, stringbuilder, preorder

this is a decision tree base on pre-order
Here is the tree fill in code

```
Position<Integer> n0 = tree.addRoot(0);
Position<Integer> n1 = tree.insertLeft(n0, 1);
Position<Integer> n3 = tree.insertRight(n0, 3);
Position<Integer> n2 = tree.insertLeft(n1, 2);
Position<Integer> r2 = tree.insertRight(n1, 1);
Position<Integer> r0 = tree.insertLeft(n2, 2);
Position<Integer> r1 = tree.insertRight(n2, 9);     
Position<Integer> r3 = tree.insertLeft(n3, 2);      
Position<Integer> r4 = tree.insertRight(n3, 8);     
Position<Integer> r5 = tree.insertLeft(r4, 4);      
Position<Integer> r6 = tree.insertRight(r4, 5);
```

below is my code, i tried to divide tree to left subtree and right subtree, and put them to an array list.but for each part, also need to consider the height of this sub-tree as a loop num

```
//calculate height of heap
int a = (int) Math.floor(Math.log(tree.size()) / Math.log(2));

List<String> input1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> input2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        Position<Integer> p1 = tree.root();
        Position<Integer> p2 = tree.root();

        //3 is the height of left side heap
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {       
            //left hand-side
            if (tree.hasLeft(p1) == true && tree.hasLeft(tree.left(p1))==true)
            {   
                input1.add("Y->Q"+tree.left(p1).element());             

                if (tree.hasLeft(tree.right(p1))==true)
                {
                    input1.add("N->Q"+tree.right(p1).element());
                }
                else
                {
                    input1.add("N->R"+tree.right(p1).element());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                input1.add("Y->R"+tree.left(p1).element());
                input1.add("N->R"+tree.right(p1).element());
            }
            p1 = tree.left(p1);

        }   

        //3 is the heap height of right
                for(int n=0;n<3;n++)
                {
                    //right hand-side
                    if (tree.hasRight(p2) == true && tree.hasLeft(tree.right(p2))==true)
                    {                       
                        input2.add("N->Q"+tree.right(p2).element());

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        input2.add("Y->R"+tree.left(p2).element());
                        input2.add("N->R"+tree.right(p2).element());
                    }

                    p2 = tree.right(p2);

                }
```

but the Output are

```
array input1: [Y->Q1, N->Q3, Y->Q2, N->R1, Y->R2, N->R9]
array input2: [N->Q3, N->Q8, Y->R4, N->R5]
```

the expected result should be

```
array input1: [Y->Q1, N->Q3, Y->Q2, N->R1, Y->R2, N->R9]
array input2: [Y->R2, N->Q8, Y->R4, N->R5]
```

and the final result i want is

```
Y->Q1:
   Y->Q2:
      Y->R2
      N->R9
   N->R1
N->Q3:
      Y->R2
      N->Q8
         Y->R4
         N->R5
```

I know it may use SringBuilder to complete the indentation with 3 spaces right for each child decision. but don't know how to do it, and before that, need fix 'array input2'

New code here

```
public static void printDecisionTree(BinaryTree<Integer> tree) {    

        Position<Integer> root = tree.root();
        boolean isLeft =true;

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        String LS = System.getProperty("line.separator");

           if(tree.hasLeft(root) || tree.hasRight(root)){
               if(isLeft)
                  output.append("Y->Q"+root.element()+LS);
               else
                  output.append("N->Q"+root.element()+LS);
           }
           else{
               if(isLeft)
                  output.append("Y->R"+root.element()+LS);
               else
                  output.append("N->R"+root.element()+LS);
           }
           if (tree.hasLeft(root)&& isLeft==true){
               printDecisionTree(tree);
           }
           if (tree.hasRight(root)&& isLeft==false){
               printDecisionTree(tree);
           }
           System.out.print(output);

    }
```

Comment: i actually dont really understand what do you mean by Y->Q/Y->R/N->Q/N->R

Comment: @JohnnyAW you can regard them as string, if left, then Y, if right then N, if no child then R, if have child, then Q:

Comment: ok, but why do you expect N->Q3 in the left-array?

Comment: @JohnnyAW i just thinking..because i want them all in pair, so maybe easier to transform to that stack output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you need to traverse the nodes and put the values in the arrays.
assume you have this:

```
public void traverse (Position<Integer> root, List<String> input, boolean isLeft){
   if(tree.hasLeft(root) || tree.hasRight(root)){
       if(isLeft)
          input.add("Y->Q"+root.element());
       else
          input.add("N->Q"+root.element());
   }
   else{
       if(isLeft)
          input.add("Y->R"+root.element());
       else
          input.add("N->R"+root.element());
   }
   if (tree.hasLeft(root)){
       traverse(tree.left(root), input, true);
   }
   if (tree.hasRight(root)){
       traverse(tree.right(root), input, false);
   }
}
```

use it in your function like this:

```
List<String> input1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> input2 = new ArrayList<String>();

Position<Integer> left = tree.left(tree.root());
Position<Integer> right = tree.right(tree.root());

traverse(left, input1, true);
traverse(right, input2, false);
```

i hope i didnt forget something:)

edit1: traverse is static now
edit2:nah, static isnt good because of tree...

Comment: but how this traverse method looking for element until the end of this tree?

Comment: its go down only if you have a left or right child. its recursive approach. you can do it in iterative way, but you will need a stack for it

Comment: so i need have a boolean to determine whether this child is left or not, but my binary tree interface don't have that method

Comment: did you try my code? i dont think you will need something else, i used only stuff you used in your code

Comment: i only have a boolean for "is root","is internal node","is external node", "has left" and "has right" :(

Comment: i dont understand you problem? can you compile your code? you give  boolean isLeft to traverse by yourself, because you know, that you execute the traverse with the left or right node, you dont need something else for it. just try my code

Comment: i tried but got error, because i changed something to fit the requirement

Comment: you dont need to change something, just take your code as you posted at the begining and add my functions, it will work. Your new code will not work, its infinite loop because of printDecisionTree(tree);